# Formula to compare time values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

Below excel formula is working fine but in some cases its not give me proper value .

Input:

```
19:20:42
24:58:36
26:11:18
```

After using this formula:

```
 =IF(TIMEVALUE(K7)>TIMEVALUE("09:00:00"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

I got the below output:

```
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
```

What I Observe if the time value is > or = 24:00:00 it will not give me the proper answer.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to Captain's excellent answer, you could also use:

```
=IF(K7>(9/24),TRUE,FALSE)
```

DateTime values are internally stored as a number of days since 1/1/1900,
therefore 1 = 1 day = 24 hours. So 9/24 = 0.375 = 9 hours  :-)

You can easily verify this by clearing the format of your DateTime cells.

---

**Edit**: note that such Boolean formula can be expressed in a shorter way without losing legibility:

```
=K7>(9/24)
```

Comment: You might need to use `VALUE(K7)` in iDevlop's also grand answer as it looked like, from your example, you have the "times" as `TEXT`...

Answer (score 3):

When you go over 24 hours, Excel counts it as the next day... and then the `TIMEVALUE` is the time the next day (i.e. 00:58:36 and 02:11:18 in your examples) and can, therefore, be before 0900.
You could do `DATEVALUE(K7)+TIMEVALUE(K7)` to ensure that you count the day part too...